# PowerShell: How to source a function like source a file?

Tags: powershell

In my main script, I will first call an init function to initiate many variables which I expected to be used in the script. One way is to use variables whose name are like `$script:var1` which are script level variable. But that's kind of ugly and I'd like to use normal variable name, so I need a mechanism to source a function just like source a file.

When source a file, all the variables in that file are available in the calling script.

Answer (score 5):

Use the same syntax that uses dot-operator, just like for sourcing files:

```
. My-Function
```

Comment: only loosely related, but google brought me here: for sourcing a file `. ./foo.ps1` worked

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in a scriptblock and dot-source that, but the rules are slightly different. You must have a space after the period to dot-source a function, and you don't with a scriptblock.

Both of these will produce 42

```
$a=0
function init {$a=42}
. init
$a

$a=0 
$init={$a=42}
.$init
$a
```